# How do I backup my contacts that are on an excel file into my nexus 5 phone?

Tags: contacts, 5.0-lollipop, microsoft-excel

I have all my contacts saved in an excel file with name and phone number headers :)
Does anyone know how can I restore them into my new nexus 5 phone ?

Comment: Should I assume, from your question, that you have no desire to sync Google contacts?

Comment: If you are signed in to a google account on your phone, you can use [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/u/0/) and import a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) of your contacts.

Comment: I did the same steps but Google didn't recognize the format or put the names and phone numbers in the comments section, they weren't correctly saved :)

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details on the file format you have if it's not saved as a standard CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Check its format 
If .CSV
Put that .CSV file into your SD-Card or internal then. 
1. Go to contact > Menu

2. Import from storage
3. Select that .CSVfile 
   Then it automatically scan and add them to your contact list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have excel application

```
Name    Given Name  Additional Name Family Name Yomi Name   Given Name Yomi Additional Name Yomi    Family Name Yomi    Name Prefix Name Suffix Initials    Nickname    Short Name  Maiden Name Birthday    Gender  Location    Billing Information Directory Server    Mileage Occupation  Hobby   Sensitivity Priority    Subject Notes   Group Membership    E-mail 1 - Type E-mail 1 - Value    E-mail 2 - Type E-mail 2 - Value    Phone 1 - Type  Phone 1 - Value Phone 2 - Type  Phone 2 - Value Phone 3 - Type  Phone 3 - Value Website 1 - Type    Website 1 - Value
```

1.Copy the above text and paste it in excel sheet. Each fields will be pasted as seperate column.

2.Now update the required field (Name , Group-membership(ex:Mycontact), Phone 1 - Type(ex:Mobile)   Phone 1 - Value(ex: 9999999999) are required). You can leave the rest as blanks.

3.Save the file as filename.csv

4.Copy the file to phone.

5.Install [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.gajdos.contacts&hl=en) app

6.Export as vcf file

7.Open contact and import vcf

[image]

Comment: Looks like the app is not available on the Play Store anymore (you may still be able to see the entry on the Play Store if you have installed it before). Any other alternatives?